# How to calculate progress rate of DRBD?

Tags: drbd

WinDRBD's progress is only visible when syncing. But I'd like to know how far has gone if the out-of-sync remains.

```
drbdsetup status foo --v --s
```

Through the detail view command, the following contents were obtained.

```
foo node-id:2 role:Primary suspended:no
    write-ordering:flush
  volume:1 minor:1 disk:UpToDate backing_dev:\DosDevices\G: quorum:yes
      size:524253532 read:7238338 written:5209825 al-writes:589 bm-writes:198 upper-pending:0 lower-pending:10
      al-suspended:no blocked:no
  Node1 node-id:1 connection:Connected role:Secondary congested:no ap-in-flight:0 rs-in-flight:7168
    volume:1 replication:SyncSource peer-disk:Inconsistent done:85.32 resync-suspended:no
        received:0 sent:1226764 out-of-sync:210484 pending:6 unacked:10 dbdt1:14.99 eta:14
```

```
done:85.32
```

This part is  known as the progress rate.

How was this calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a resource becomes disconnected, the `out-of-sync` counter will begin to increment on the peer that is currently Primary. When the resource reconnects, the bitmaps (stored in DRBD's metadata) are compared to determine which blocks became `out-of-sync` while disconnected, and proceeds to resync those blocks in the background. Any writes that occur during a background resync are immediately replicated, and if that write happens to touch a block that's a part of the background resync, it's removed from the resync queue (since it was updated by the foreground replication).

Comment: Thank you! it was helpful! If you know one more thing, is there any way I can do the math to get the progress number?
This is because I want to know the progress rate even when the synchronization is stopped.

Comment: because the sync rate is variable/dynamic, you cannot really know for sure, but you can get close by dividing the number of `out-of-sync` blocks (which is displayed in `KiB`) by your expected resync rate.

Comment: Matt Thanks for your kind reply. I thought that I should be able to use the ```done``` information in the detailed information.